# Is it possible to use an outputfile as an inputfile later on in code (C++ I/O files)

Tags: c++

So what I did was this;

```
ifstream infile("warehouse.txt"); ffile("updated.txt");
ofstream outfile("updated.txt");
```

basically what I want to do is read from the inputfile 'warehouse.txt' and store contents in an array and then add this array and an extra array to outputfile 'updated.txt'.

Then I want to use 'updated.txt' as an input file as shown in the code above is this allowed, I basically want to store all the data on updated.txt into one big array i.e combine the two arrays, is this allowed? I tried it and my compiler seemed to screw up and I was reading about using vectors instead but am struggling to understand them. thanks.

here is my overall code what I wanted to do was basically take from an input file the 'fruitname' and its corresponding quantity from an input file. store extra entries in an extraarray and then put both these arrays in an output file as stated above and then use that output as an input file so I can aggreagte the data.

THE PROBLEM:

When I try to store from the updated.txt to array my cout's show that I get random numbers in place of what should be the fruitname and its number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct items {
    string name;
    int quantity;
} items_t;

void fileopenchecker (ifstream &FILE);
int readfromfile (ifstream &FILE, items_t fruit[]);
int extrarray (items_t fruit[]);
void writetooutputfile (ofstream &OFILE, items_t fruit[], int size);
void combinearrays (ifstream &final, items_t overallfruit[], int total);

int main()
{
    const int MAX_SIZE = 150;
    int Nfruit = 0;
    int Nextrafruit = 0;
    int total;
    std::ifstream infile("warehouse.txt");
    std::ofstream outfile("updated.txt");
    std::ifstream ffile("updated.txt");
    items_t extrafruit[MAX_SIZE], fruit[MAX_SIZE], overallfruit[MAX_SIZE];

    fileopenchecker(infile);
    Nextrafruit = extrarray(extrafruit);
    Nfruit = readfromfile(infile, fruit);
    total = Nextrafruit + Nfruit;
    infile.close();
    writetooutputfile(outfile, fruit, Nfruit);
    writetooutputfile(outfile, extrafruit, Nextrafruit);

    combinearrays (ffile, overallfruit, total);

    ffile.close();

    return 0;
}

void combinearrays (ifstream &final, items_t overallfruit[], int total){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<total; i++){
        final >> overallfruit[i].name >> overallfruit[i].quantity;
        cout << overallfruit[i].name << overallfruit[i].quantity << endl;
    }
}

void fileopenchecker (ifstream &FILE){
    if(!FILE.is_open()){
        cout << "Your file was NOT detected!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        cout << "Your file was detected" << endl;
    }
}

 int readfromfile (ifstream &FILE, items_t fruit[]){

    int   entries = 0;

    while(!FILE.eof()){

        FILE >> fruit[entries].name >> fruit[entries].quantity;

        cout << fruit[entries].name << fruit[entries].quantity << endl;
        entries++;
    }
    return entries;
}

int extrarray (items_t fruit[]){
    int runner=1, exentries =0;
        while(runner==1){
            cout << "Would you like to add entries to your file? (YES-->1 NO-->0)" << endl;
            cin >> runner;

            if(runner==0){
                break;
            }

            //take the itemname and quantity and stores it in the array.
            cout << "Enter the name of the fruit and its quantity" << endl;
            cin >> fruit[exentries].name >> fruit[exentries].quantity;

            //debugging:
            cout << fruit[exentries].name << fruit[exentries].quantity << endl;
            exentries++;
        }
    return exentries;
}

void writetooutputfile (ofstream &OFILE, items_t fruit[], int size){
int entries = 0;

    while(entries < size){
        cout << fruit[entries].name << fruit[entries].quantity << endl;
        OFILE << fruit[entries].name << fruit[entries].quantity << endl;
        entries++;
    }
}
```

Comment: To answer your question, yes.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to, but depending on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, seems like it would be easier to just keep the output in memory rather than writing only to read it later.

Comment: @Paddyd: looks like an answer to me.

Comment: "I tried it and my compiler seemed to screw up" - So what happened?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please describe what you want to achieve. As unspecific as your questions are one can only answer: "everything is possible", but I am convinced that this would not help.

Comment: You could lark about with files, but I am sure the code will be neater with vectors. Could you show what you tried for the vectors that went wrong?

Comment: @Joni so when I read from the file, the compiler shows a lot of random numbers where it should be the item name in the file and its corresponding quantity.

Answer (score 0):

*"I want to do is read from the inputfile 'warehouse.txt'"*

```
{
    std::ifstream ifs("warehouse.txt");
    // reading from ifs ...
```

... *"to outputfile 'updated.txt'"*

```
    std::ofstream ofs("updated.txt");
    // writing to ofs ...
}
```

... *"Then I want to use 'updated.txt' as an input file"* ~> create another instance of `ifstream`:

```
{
    std::ifstream ifs2("updated.txt");
    // reading from ifs2 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it's possible to to use just two file streams if you use `std::fstream`.  For example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    std::ifstream infile("a.txt");
    // create file for both reading and writing
    std::fstream ffile("b.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);

    // read contents of file a and write to file b
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
        ffile << line << std::endl;
    }

    // flush the output to disk
    ffile.flush();

    // go back to the start of the output file before reading from it
    ffile.seekg(0);

    // read contents of output file again.
    while (std::getline(ffile, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```